# Unable to query HIVE Parquet based EXTERNAL table from spark-sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, mapr

We have an External Hive Table which is stored as Parquet. I am not the owner of the schema in which this hive-parquet table is so don't have much info.

The Problem here is when in try to Query that table from spark-sql>(Shell prompt) Not by using scala like spark.read.parquet("path"), I am getting 0 records stating "Unable to infer schema". But when i created a Managed Table by using CTAS in my personal schema just for testing i was able to query it from the spark-sql>(Shell prompt)

When i try it from `spark-shell> via spark.read.parquet("../../00000_0").show(10)` , I was able to see the data.
So this clears that something is wrong between

> `External Hive table - Parquet - Spark-SQL(shell)`

If locating Schema would be the issue then it should behave same while accessing through spark session (spark.read.parquet(""))

I am using MapR 5.2, Spark version 2.1.0

Please suggest what can be the issue

Comment: It Obvious that you dont have permission to access the table since you are not the owner schema. You dont know which table it is and it makes me suprised how you query the table from spark-sql cli.

If you know the table and have permission you can query the table from spark-sql cli.

Otherwise as you said you can read using the spark session from spark shell `park.read.parquet`, which still requires permission to access the file.

Comment: There is no permission issue. I can query the same table from HIVE with the same user but NOT from spark-sql cli

Comment: Could you please check the spark is able to access the hive metastore. Please put the hive-site.xml in the spark config if not.

Comment: Yes. Spark is able to access HIVE Metastore

Comment: Could you please provide the schema of the parquet file from hive and from the df.printSchema()